# Wann kann man „mit“ und „bei“ benutzen?

Tags: preposition

Wann benutzt man „mit“ und „bei“?
Ich weiß, dass beides Dative Präposition sind und auch „with“ auf englisch bedeuten. Aber ich weiß nicht, wann kann ich mit oder bei benutzen.

Comment: Was sagen die Dir bekannten Wörterbücher?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30355/helfen-bei-vs-helfen-mit

Answer (score 2):

Die Grundbedeutung kann man sich so veranschaulichen: *mit* bedeutet, dass A und B  *dasselbe* tun; *bei* bedeutet, dass Person A unter dem Umstand B etwas tut.

> Ich gehe mit Julia essen = zwei Personen essen gemeinsam
>
> Ich gehe bei Giulio essen = der Sprecher ist der Gast und Giulio ist der Wirt.

Es geht also im elementarsten Fall um *Begleitung* gegenüber *Ort* oder der *Art und Weise*.

Natürlich gibt es noch weitere Bedeutungen - *mit* kann z.B. auch das *Mittel* ausdrücken (eine Schraube mit einem Schraubendreher lösen). All diese kann man nur durch Studieren vieler Beispiele lernen.